# How to inject html elements into custom component

Tags: angular

I Need to pass html Elements into a custom created components via the template file. Let's imagine I have a component called `<app-card></app-card>` that represents a Card layout with specific style, but I don't want to create this component everytime from Scratch when I Need it. So it would be a good Approach I think to create a custom UI component for this element. But now when I use this component, I want to pass some other html Elements into it, for example a H2 and some p-tags:

```
<app-card>
  <h2>New child I passed</h2>
  <p>And another one</p>
</app-card>
```

When I test it, this way wouldn't work. Does anyone know how I can achive that nested components?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ng-content will be helpful in creating the configurable components. You need to use  inside the app-card component. Content that has been placed within the opening and the closing tags of the app-card will be projected in

app-card component

```
<div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Custom component

```
<app-card>
  <h2>New child I passed</h2>
  <p>And another one</p>
</app-card>
```

Here h2 and p tag will be rendered inside the ng-content. For more info search for content projection in angular

Comment: That helped me a lot!!! Thank you very much @Indragith!!! Have a great day!

Comment: Calm down, it was so Fresh I couldn't accept it Right away :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ng-content` inside your custom component to make it work.

app-card.component.html:

```
<div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Then you can use it like you wanted to:

```
<app-card>
  <h2>New child I passed</h2>
  <p>And another one</p>
</app-card>
```

You can go a step further, if you need to and create multiple projections:

```
<div>
    <div class="head">
        <ng-content select="h1"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <ng-content select="div"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
<app-card>
    <h1>My card title</h1>
    <div>My special div</div>
    <span>All the rest which doesn't belong to a special selector goes into the default ng-content</span>
</app-card>
```

Hope this helps.